# AutoLayOut Issue - Adding animated view from left hand side to viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, autolayout

I am using **AutoLayOut** in my application. I am adding UIView from left hand side to my view controller. On click of button I open view from left hand side. My UIView is named as sideView. To open sidemenu, following is my code.

```
- (IBAction)openSideMenu:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self.sideView setFrame:CGRectMake(0 - self.view.frame.size.width, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"OpenFromLeftSide" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
    [self.sideView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

For closing the sideMenu I have button in sideMenu. By clicking the button I am closing sidemenu as follows:

```
- (IBAction)closeSideMenu:(UIButton *)sender {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"CloseSideMenu" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
    [self.sideView setFrame:CGRectMake(0 - self.view.frame.size.width, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Above both functionality working fine.

Now problem is constraint which I assigned to button inside sidemenu(SubView).
I assigned following 3 constraints to sidemenu.

1. Top space to superview
2. Bottom space to superview.
3. Set right edges to superview i.e. sidemenu

But the 3rd constraint is not shown properly. In simulator the right edges of button is not set with the right edges of my view(Sidemenu)

Can any one tell me how can I set constraint that my button can strictly be attached to right edges of subview(sidemenu).

Comment: you want the button to have the same width as the `sideView` ?

Comment: @user3783005: width of button is around 46 pixels, height is same is the view's height but it should be most right hand side to the view.

Comment: @user3783005: without using AutoLayOut, button's frame should be [self.btnCloseMenu setFrame:CGRectMake(self.sideView.frame.size.width - self.btnCloseMenu.frame.size.width, 0, self.btnCloseMenu.frame.size.width, self.sideView.frame.size.height)];

Comment: instead edges assign leading or trailing constraint to your button according to your requirement.

Comment: i would suggest you do it without constraints, but if you insist just give it top and bottom to superview, aspect ratio to superview and to itself and leading and trailng to superview

Comment: If you required fix width so you set more two constraint to get required result. Fix width and trailing to superview..